# Extracting capital words and extracting the last word in a string

Tags: regex, r

I have a df that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
    x = c(
        "800 Block of MAIN ST",
        "100 Block of CHESTNUT AV", 
        "BAY ST / WELLINGTON ST", 
        "LARKIN ST / ELLIS ST",
        "MAPLE ST / WELLINGTON ST", 
        "MEANDERING RD / MAIN ST"),
    y = rnorm(6))
```

I want to extract the first street name and the last street type.

Desired Output:

```
                         x          y  x.1        x.2
1     800 Block of MAIN ST -0.6745405  MAIN       ST
2 100 Block of CHESTNUT AV -1.1316017  CHESTNUT   AV 
3   BAY ST / WELLINGTON ST  1.2887577  BAY        ST
4     LARKIN ST / ELLIS ST  1.4606264  LARKIN     ST
5 MAPLE ST / WELLINGTON ST  0.6538595  MAPLE      ST
6  MEANDERING RD / MAIN ST  0.8472322  MEANDERING ST
```

Comment: what about the last three? you want both of them? in separate columns? can you add the desired output for this example under the description of the desired output

Comment: Please post an example of the output that you would expect from the example provided (the actual output, not the description).

Comment: Please be more explicit about your desired output

Comment: Also, it would help to include a case like "BLVD" and how you expect it to be handled.

Comment: `m <- gregexpr('[A-Z]{3,} [A-Z]+', df$x, perl = TRUE); regmatches(df$x, m)` maybe

Comment: @rawr @/Pierre Lafortune @/Frank.... fixed.

Comment: @PierreLafortune because ST is the last street type in the string.

Comment: I see. The answer reflects that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df <- within(df, st_name <- sub(".*?([A-Z]{3,}).*", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE))

df <- within(df, st_type <- sub(".+? ([A-Z]+)$", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE))
#                         x           y    st_name st_type
#1     800 Block of MAIN ST  1.92908789       MAIN      ST
#2 100 Block of CHESTNUT AV  0.02487045   CHESTNUT      AV
#3   BAY ST / WELLINGTON ST -2.33411242        BAY      ST
#4     LARKIN ST / ELLIS ST -1.17946144     LARKIN      ST
#5 MAPLE ST / WELLINGTON ST  0.12913797      MAPLE      ST
#6  MEANDERING RD / MAIN ST -0.94150930 MEANDERING      ST
```

Or if you aren't fond of using `within`:

```
df$st_name <- sub(".*?([A-Z]{3,}).*", "\\1", df$x, perl=TRUE)
df$st_type <- sub(".+? ([A-Z]+)$", "\\1", df$x, perl=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
library(stringr)
df[,c("street", "type")] <- list(str_extract(df$x, "[A-Z]{3,}"), str_extract(df$x, "[A-Z]+$"))
#                          x          y     street type
# 1     800 Block of MAIN ST  0.7787495       MAIN   ST
# 2 100 Block of CHESTNUT AV -0.7069777   CHESTNUT   AV
# 3   BAY ST / WELLINGTON ST -0.2365061        BAY   ST
# 4     LARKIN ST / ELLIS ST  0.1399500     LARKIN   ST
# 5 MAPLE ST / WELLINGTON ST -0.3423978      MAPLE   ST
# 6  MEANDERING RD / MAIN ST  0.6434969 MEANDERING   ST
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a similar solution using a single regex expression combined with the new `tstrsplit` function from [the development version of `data.table`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
library(data.table) # v1.9.5+
setDT(df)[, c("street", "type") := 
              tstrsplit(sub(".*?([A-Z]{3,}).*([A-Z]{2,})", "\\1,\\2", x), ",")]
df
#                           x          y     street type
# 1:     800 Block of MAIN ST -1.4391801       MAIN   ST
# 2: 100 Block of CHESTNUT AV  1.4917789   CHESTNUT   AV
# 3:   BAY ST / WELLINGTON ST -0.0369405        BAY   ST
# 4:     LARKIN ST / ELLIS ST  0.7320230     LARKIN   ST
# 5: MAPLE ST / WELLINGTON ST  0.7189120      MAPLE   ST
# 6:  MEANDERING RD / MAIN ST -0.9836794 MEANDERING   ST
```

---

Basically, the idea here is to capture both groups within a single `sub` call, concatenate them with a comma (you can choose something else if you like) and then perform a *transpose sting split* (`tstrsplit`) in order to convert them into two separate columns while creating them by reference (using the `:=` operator)